# Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova Your plugins may be out of date

Tags: javascript, cordova, angularfire2, ionic3

there is run time error in ionic 3 cli ionic cordova run android. when i install angularfire2 cant build this project.

> [10:25:54]  webpack started ...
>   [WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your
>          plugins may be out of date.
>   Error: ./~/firebase/app/shared_promise.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill' in 'D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\no
>   de_modules\firebase\app'
>   resolve 'promise-polyfill' in 'D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\node_modules\firebase\app'
>     Parsed request is a module
>     using description file: D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\node_modules\firebase\package.json (re
>   lative path: ./app)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>     after using description file: D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\node_modules\firebase\package.js
>   on (relative path: ./app)
>       resolve as module
>         looking for modules in D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\node_modules
>           using description file: D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\package.json (relative path: ./n
>   ode_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\package.json (relative pat
>   h: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\package.json (relative path: .
>   /node_modules/promise-polyfill)
>               as directory
>                 D:\ReactiveSpace\june\Ionic\Littldfde\node_modules\promise-polyfill doesn't exist
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you config.xml file and check for any conflict or check for the version number may you are using depricated version and change it to requested one